# match rows from one file to columns in another file

Tags: awk

I have two files where one file contain names in each row as follows:-

```
GTX-1175F-223-RGXC
GTX-1135F-223-RGXC
GTX-1145F-223-RGXC
GTX-1155F-223-RGXC
GTX-1185F-223-RGXC
```

Second file contains values for each of the names stated in file1 like this:

```
GTX-1175F-223-RGXC GTX-1135F-223-RGXC GTX-1155F-223-RGXC GTX-1175F-240-RGXC
2.3 12 5.6 4
3.4 4.5 0.8 6
3.8 89 0.2 4
```

Expected output

```
GTX-1175F-223-RGXC GTX-1135F-223-RGXC GTX-1155F-223-RGXC
2.3 12 5.6 
3.4 4.5 0.8
3.8 89 0.2
```

I would like to have an output where the column names in file2 that match to row names in file 1 are extracted along with values.

If it was column matching it would have been like this

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ a[$1]=$0;next } ($1 in a)' file2 file1
```

Could anyone please help me with a one liner in awk.

Thank you

Comment: I understand that part, I have failed and that 's why seeked help or guidance.

Comment: please post your attempted code then we can surely help

Comment: If it was for columns, it could have been something like this awk 'FNR==NR{ a[$1]=$0;next } ($1 in a)' file2 file1

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66640149/edit) and place this attempted code in question body. Comments are not the right place to check your code.

Comment: Also it would be good if you can show your expected output in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this 2 pass `awk` solution:

```sh
awk 'FNR==NR {
   seen[$1]
   next
}
{
   s = ""
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
      if (FNR==1 && $i in seen)
         cols[i]
      if (i in cols)
         s = (s=="" ? "" : s OFS) $i
   }
   print s
}' file1 file2

GTX-1175F-223-RGXC GTX-1135F-223-RGXC GTX-1155F-223-RGXC
2.3 12 5.6
3.4 4.5 0.8
3.8 89 0.2
```

Comment: for some strange reason I get blank as an output for both your and Glenn's code. Same input file.

Comment: Can you do `cat -vte file1` to check it's output and see if you don't have `^M` (DOS line ending) by any chance.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @anubhava's answer:

```sh
awk '
  NR == FNR {seen[$1]; next}
  FNR == 1 {for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) keep[i] = ($i in seen)}
  {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if (keep[i]) printf "%s%s", $i, OFS
    print "" 
  }
' file{1,2}
```

```
GTX-1175F-223-RGXC GTX-1135F-223-RGXC GTX-1155F-223-RGXC
2.3 12 5.6
3.4 4.5 0.8
3.8 89 0.2
```

Comment: I wrote exactly this earlier but enhanced it because it leaves trailing spaces on each line.